# Flutter: First time user onboarding with AWS Amplify

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

Im looking for a way to show a first time on boarding screen when you register with the app. It is required for me because users must join a Model called families and none of the widgets will show up if the user isn't part of the model.

I tried creating a boolean flag under the user model and set it to false when the user registers but I wasn't sure how to set it as an inital value.